# Three.js (GLSL) — Canvas resize

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader

I am trying to preserve the proportions at least a little when the window is resized to smaller sizes at [the CodePen here](https://codepen.io/pkid/pen/MWYGjLB). Currently it turns out to be really hard to see the lines and the interaction on mobile. Do you have a solution for this? Maybe it makes sense to double the scale on resize based on the window but I am a bit lost on how I can implement it.

The responsible part of the JS:

```js
onWindowResize();
 window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
 
}

function onWindowResize(event) {
 container.style.height = window.innerHeight+"px";
 container.style.width = window.innerWidth+"px";
 
 canvasWidth = container.offsetWidth;
 canvasHeight = container.offsetHeight;
 //send new size value to the shader and resize the window
 uniforms.resolution.value.x = canvasWidth;
 uniforms.resolution.value.y = canvasHeight;
 
 //var res = canvasWidth / cols;
 //rows = canvasHeight / res;
 uniforms.colsrows.value.x = cols;
 uniforms.colsrows.value.y = rows;//rows;
 
 renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
}
```

Here is the pen:

```js
//Create var for the contenair, the webGL 3D scene, uniforms to bind into shader and timer

var container;
var camera, scene, renderer;
var uniforms;
var startTime;


var cols = 50.;
var rows  = 50.0;

init(); //init scene
animate(); //updateScene

function init() {
 //get contenaire
 container = document.getElementById('container');
 
 //Create THREE.JS scene and timer
 startTime = Date.now();
 camera = new THREE.Camera();
 camera.position.z = 1;
 scene = new THREE.Scene();
 
 //create a simple plance
 var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(16, 9);
 
 //create uniform table which provide all our GLSL binding
 uniforms = {
  time: { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
  resolution: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() },
  colsrows: {type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2()},
  mouse: {type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2()}
 };
 
 //create THREE.JS material
 var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
 //set shaders and uniforms into material
  uniforms: uniforms,
  vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
  fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent
 } );

 //create mesh, add it to the scene
 var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
 scene.add(mesh);
 
 //create renderer and add it to the DOM
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
 container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
 
 //check window for resize This will give us the proper resolution values to bind
 onWindowResize();
 window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
 
}

function onWindowResize(event) {
 container.style.height = window.innerHeight+"px";
 container.style.width = window.innerWidth+"px";
 
 canvasWidth = container.offsetWidth;
 canvasHeight = container.offsetHeight;
 //send new size value to the shader and resize the window
 uniforms.resolution.value.x = canvasWidth;
 uniforms.resolution.value.y = canvasHeight;
 
 //var res = canvasWidth / cols;
 //rows = canvasHeight / res;
 uniforms.colsrows.value.x = cols;
 uniforms.colsrows.value.y = rows;//rows;
 
 renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
}

function animate() {
 render();
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function render() {
 var currentTime = Date.now();
 var elaspedSeconds =  (currentTime - startTime) / 1000.0;
 var maxTime = 4.0;
 var normTime = (elaspedSeconds % maxTime) / maxTime;
 uniforms.time.value = elaspedSeconds * 1.0;

 renderer.render(scene, camera);
}


function move(ev){
  mx = ev.clientX
   my = ev.clientY;
 // console.log(mx+" , "+my);
 
 uniforms.mouse.value.x = mx;
 uniforms.mouse.value.y = my;
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', move)
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background : #1a1a1a;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  cursor: none;
}

#container{
 background : black;
 color : white;
   margin: auto;
 width : 500px;
 height : 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div> 

<!-- GLSL SCRIPT -->
<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
 void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
 }
</script>

<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  #define TWO_PI 6.28318530718
  #define EPSILON 0.000011
  uniform vec2 resolution;
  uniform float time;
  uniform vec2 colsrows;
  uniform vec2 mouse;
 
  float HueToRGB(float f1, float f2, float hue)
  {
   if (hue < 0.0)
    hue += 1.0;
   else if (hue > 1.0)
    hue -= 1.0;
   float res;
   if ((6.0 * hue) < 1.0)
    res = f1 + (f2 - f1) * 6.0 * hue;
   else if ((2.0 * hue) < 1.0)
    res = f2;
   else if ((3.0 * hue) < 2.0)
    res = f1 + (f2 - f1) * ((2.0 / 3.0) - hue) * 6.0;
   else
    res = f1;
   return res;
  }


  vec3 HSLToRGB(vec3 hsl)
  {
   vec3 rgb;

   if (hsl.y == 0.0)
    rgb = vec3(hsl.z); // Luminance
   else
   {
    float f2;

    if (hsl.z < 0.5)
     f2 = hsl.z * (1.0 + hsl.y);
    else
     f2 = (hsl.z + hsl.y) - (hsl.y * hsl.z);

    float f1 = 2.0 * hsl.z - f2;

    rgb.r = HueToRGB(f1, f2, hsl.x + (1.0/3.0));
    rgb.g = HueToRGB(f1, f2, hsl.x);
    rgb.b= HueToRGB(f1, f2, hsl.x - (1.0/3.0));
   }

   return rgb;
  }
 
  mat2 rotate2d(float _angle){
   return mat2(cos(_angle),-sin(_angle),
      sin(_angle),cos(_angle));
  }
  
  vec2 rotateFrom(vec2 uv, vec2 center, float angle){
   vec2 uv_ = uv - center;
   uv_ =  rotate2d(angle) * uv_;
   uv_ = uv_ + center;

   return uv_;
  }
  
  float random(float value){
   return fract(sin(value) * 43758.5453123);
  }
  
  float random(vec2 tex){
   return fract(sin(dot(tex.xy, vec2(12.9898, 78.233))) * 43758.5453123);
  }
  
  vec2 random2D(vec2 uv){
   uv = vec2(dot(uv, vec2(127.1, 311.7)), dot(uv, vec2(269.5, 183.3)));
   //return -1.0 + 2.0 * fract(sin(uv) * 43758.5453123);
   return fract(sin(uv) * 43758.5453123); //return without offset on x, y
  }

  vec3 random3D(vec3 uv){
   uv = vec3(dot(uv, vec3(127.1, 311.7, 120.9898)), dot(uv, vec3(269.5, 183.3, 150.457)), dot(uv, vec3(380.5, 182.3, 170.457)));
   return -1.0 + 2.0 * fract(sin(uv) * 43758.5453123);
  }
 
  float cubicCurve(float value){
   return value * value * (3.0 - 2.0 * value); // custom cubic curve
  }

  vec2 cubicCurve(vec2 value){
   return value * value * (3.0 - 2.0 * value); // custom cubic curve
  }

  vec3 cubicCurve(vec3 value){
   return value * value * (3.0 - 2.0 * value); // custom cubic curve
  }

  float noise(vec2 uv){
   vec2 iuv = floor(uv);
   vec2 fuv = fract(uv);
   vec2 suv = cubicCurve(fuv);

   float dotAA_ = dot(random2D(iuv + vec2(0.0)), fuv - vec2(0.0));
   float dotBB_ = dot(random2D(iuv + vec2(1.0, 0.0)), fuv - vec2(1.0, 0.0));
   float dotCC_ = dot(random2D(iuv + vec2(0.0, 1.0)), fuv - vec2(0.0, 1.0));
   float dotDD_ = dot(random2D(iuv + vec2(1.0, 1.0)), fuv - vec2(1.0, 1.0));

   return mix(
    mix(dotAA_, dotBB_, suv.x),
    mix(dotCC_, dotDD_, suv.x),
    suv.y);
  }

  float noise(vec3 uv){
   vec3 iuv = floor(uv);
   vec3 fuv = fract(uv);
   vec3 suv = cubicCurve(fuv);

   float dotAA_ = dot(random3D(iuv + vec3(0.0)), fuv - vec3(0.0));
   float dotBB_ = dot(random3D(iuv + vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)), fuv - vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
   float dotCC_ = dot(random3D(iuv + vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)), fuv - vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
   float dotDD_ = dot(random3D(iuv + vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)), fuv - vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0));

   float dotEE_ = dot(random3D(iuv + vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)), fuv - vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
   float dotFF_ = dot(random3D(iuv + vec3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)), fuv - vec3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0));
   float dotGG_ = dot(random3D(iuv + vec3(0.0, 1.0, 1.0)), fuv - vec3(0.0, 1.0, 1.0));
   float dotHH_ = dot(random3D(iuv + vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)), fuv - vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));

   float passH0 = mix(
    mix(dotAA_, dotBB_, suv.x),
    mix(dotCC_, dotDD_, suv.x),
    suv.y);

   float passH1 = mix(
    mix(dotEE_, dotFF_, suv.x),
    mix(dotGG_, dotHH_, suv.x),
    suv.y);

   return mix(passH0, passH1, suv.z);
  }
 
  float drawLine(vec2 uv, vec2 p1, vec2 p2, float r)
  {
   //from https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MtlSDr
   vec2 l = p2 - p1;
   float L = length(l);
   float L2 = L*L;

   float d1 = length(uv - p1);
   float d2 = length(uv - p2);
   float d  = min(d1, d2);
   float ds = dot(uv - p1, l);
   if (ds >= 0.0 && ds <= L2)
   {
    vec2 n = vec2(-l.y, l.x) / L;
    d = min(d, abs(dot(uv - p1, n)));
   }

   return 1.0 - smoothstep(0.0, 0.01, d - r);
  }
 
  vec2 fishey(vec2 uv, vec2 center, float ratio, float dist){
     vec2 puv = uv + vec2(1.0);
    //center coords
     vec2 m = vec2(center.x, center.y/ratio) + vec2(1.0);
     //vector from center to current fragment
     vec2 d = puv - m;
     // distance of pixel from center
     float r = sqrt(dot(d, d)); 
     //amount of effect
     float power = ( TWO_PI / (2.0 * sqrt(dot(m, m)))) * mix(0.1, 0.4, pow(dist, 0.75));
     //radius of 1:1 effect
     float bind;
     if (power > 0.0) bind = sqrt(dot(m, m));//stick to corners
     //else {if (ratio < 1.0) bind = m.x; else bind = m.y;}//stick to borders

     //Weird formulas
     vec2 nuv;
     if (power > 0.0)//fisheye
    nuv = m + normalize(d) * tan(r * power) * bind / tan( bind * power);
     else if (power < 0.0)//antifisheye
      nuv = m + normalize(d) * atan(r * -power * 10.0) * bind / atan(-power * bind * 10.0);
     else 
    nuv = puv;//no effect for power = 1.0

   return nuv - vec2(1.0);
  }
 
  vec4 addGrain(vec2 uv, float time, float grainIntensity){
      float grain = random(fract(uv * time)) * grainIntensity;
      return vec4(vec3(grain), 1.0);
  }
  
  void main(){
   vec2 ouv = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;
   vec2 uv = ouv;
   
   float ratio = resolution.x / resolution.y;
   vec2 nmouse = vec2(mouse.x, mouse.y) / resolution.xy;
   nmouse.y = 1.0 - nmouse.y;
   float maxDist = 0.35;
   float blurEdge = maxDist * 0.5;
   float blurEdge2 = maxDist * 1.0;
   vec2 mouseToUV = (uv - nmouse) / vec2(1.0, ratio);
   float mouseDistance = 1.0 - smoothstep(maxDist - blurEdge, maxDist, length(mouseToUV));
   float mouseDistance2 = 1.0 - smoothstep(maxDist - blurEdge2, maxDist, length(mouseToUV));
   
   
   uv = fishey(uv, nmouse, ratio,  mouseDistance2);
   uv = rotateFrom(uv, vec2(0.5), time * 0.1);
   //animate y
   //wave
   uv.y /= ratio;
   vec2 basedUV = uv + vec2(1.0);
   float complexityX = 10.0;
   float complexityY = 10.0;
   float maxAmp = mix(0.05, 0.75, mouseDistance);
   float amp = 0.01 * mouseDistance + noise(vec3(basedUV.x * complexityX, basedUV.y * complexityY, time * 0.1)) * maxAmp;
   float theta = time + mouseDistance + basedUV.y * (TWO_PI);
   uv.x = fract(uv.x + sin(theta) * amp);
   //divide into cols rows
   vec2 nuv = uv * colsrows;
   vec2 fuv = fract(nuv);
   vec2 iuv = floor(nuv);
   
   float minSpeed = 1.0;
   float maxSpeed = 5.0;
   float speed = minSpeed + random(floor(uv.x * colsrows.x)) * (maxSpeed - minSpeed);
   fuv.y = fract(fuv.y + time * speed);
   
   //draw dash line
   float minWeight = 0.005 + random(vec2(iuv.x, 0.0)) * 0.05;
   float strokeWeight = mix(minWeight, minWeight * 5.0, mouseDistance);
   float dlineWidth = mix(1.0, 0.25 - strokeWeight, mouseDistance);//0.5 - strokeWeight;
   float dline = drawLine(fuv, vec2(0.5, 0.5 - dlineWidth * 0.5), vec2(0.5, 0.5 + dlineWidth * 0.5), strokeWeight);
   
   float randIndexHue = random(vec2(iuv.x + floor(time), 0.0));
   float noiseHue = noise(vec3(randIndexHue, randIndexHue, time));
   float hue = mix(0.111, 0.138, randIndexHue + (noiseHue * 0.5));
   vec4 grain = addGrain(ouv, time, 0.15);
   //vec3 color = HSLToRGB(vec3(hue, 1.0, 0.5));
   //vec3 bgColor = HSLToRGB(vec3(0.772, mix(0.75, 1.0, mouseDistance), mix(0.1, 0.25, mouseDistance)));
      vec3 color = vec3(1.0);
   vec3 bgColor = vec3(0.0);
   float val = dline * (mouseDistance * 0.5 + 0.5);
   
   vec3 albedo = mix(bgColor, color, val);
   
   gl_FragColor = vec4(albedo, 1.0) + grain;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thickness of the lines is computed in `drawLine` and depends on the parameters to [`smoothstep`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/smoothstep.xhtml):

> ```c
> float drawLine(vec2 uv, vec2 p1, vec2 p2, float r)
> {
>    // [...]
>
>    return 1.0 - smoothstep(0.0, 0.01, d - r);
> }
> ```

Increase the parameter to *edge1*, to generate "thicker" lines (e.g. 0.1):

```c
float drawLine(vec2 uv, vec2 p1, vec2 p2, float r)
{
    // [...]

    return 1.0 - smoothstep(0.0, 0.1, d - r);
}
```

---

You can add an additional uniform variable for the line:

```c
uniform float thickness;

float drawLine(vec2 uv, vec2 p1, vec2 p2, float r)
{
    // [...]

    return 1.0 - smoothstep(0.0, thickness, d - r);
}
```

```js
uniforms = {
    // [...]

    thickness: { type: "f", value: 0.1 },
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. This really helps with the line thickness but I think I was not so clear in my question. I am mainly wondering how to change how the canvas scales for adapting to smaller screen sizes. Right now on mobile everything scales to such a small size that the bulge interaction around the mouse is also so small (in addition to the lines). I was wondering if it would be possible to make the entire canvas maybe double the container in size (or window width/height) when it is resized so that the entire interaction is more clear in smaller screens . Do you it can be done?

Comment: @pkid Sorry I don't get it. Do you want to adapt `cols` and `rows` dependent on the size of the canvas?

Comment: Maybe the CodePen here makes it a bit more clear: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QmLvQL I do not want the contents to scale to such a small size that both the lines and the interaction is kind of lost in smaller screens. Maybe the solution is resizing the canvas with no scaling of the contents or scaling the contents in a way that they are larger than they are currently in smaller screens. Hopefully I am a bit more clear.

Comment: @pkid You mean you want to scale dependent on the size of the display rather than on the resolution of the display? Or do you mean `uniforms.colsrows.value.x = canvasWidth / cols;`, `uniforms.colsrows.value.y = canvasHeight / rows;`

Comment: I mean not scaling at all even if the window is resized. They have a similar discussion at this link yet I am not sure how I can implement it in this instance: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-resize-canvas-without-resizing-renderer-or-scaling-contents/2065/12